# Golang - Get Git username & repo list from token

Tags: git, go

I want to extract the list of git repositories on the basis of oauth token.
And I want to write a common code for github / gitlab & bitbucket.

Most probably, first I may need to extract username from token and then I will need to extract the list.. Like Github documentation suggests.

`https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user`
`https://api.github.com/users/<username>/repos`

But, this will only help me with github.
I have looked into `https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git/v5#Repository`
because it works with all git platforms. But, I couldn't find a repo listing function (based on oauth token)

What is the best way to do it ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: That's because Git doesn't have authentication. Something outside Git *always* provides the authentication; if that's oauth, that's fine, but it could be some other method. You can't assume oauth here, and if you assume oauth, you can't get information from systems that use something else. There's no standard way to list repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard uniform way to get this information.  When you use Git, you provide it authentication credentials which it uses to talk to the server, and that server, whether it is GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket, your own Apache instance, or otherwise, either accepts it or rejects it.  There is no requirement that the credentials provide any more functionality than that.

In the case of GitHub, you can use the API to get that information *provided* it's an OAuth token or a PAT and it has the `user` scope.  GitHub has other kinds of tokens which can be used for a clone which cannot be used for the API, and of course any token which lacks the `user` scope won't work.  I should point out that the for GitHub's tokens, the username isn't embedded in the token (as [they've documented on their blog](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/)), so you really do have to use the API.

GitLab may also have an API for this which you can use, but there won't be a single way to work with all repositories, and it may not be possible to determine which domain to use from the token type.  For example, github.com and GitHub Enterprise Server (the on-premises option) will issue tokens that look identical, but of course the tokens will only work on the system that issued them.